# Focus effect in a RecyclerView - how to bring to front an item?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to create a "focus" effect once the user clicks an item in the recycler view. Look at the image below, the second one is the effect I wish to have.

[image: Example]

I've tried to get the RecyclerView's clicked item and bring it to the front and show a dark/transparent overlay covering all the others.

This is my view hierarchy:

RelativeLayout

--- Recycler View

--- View (dark overlay)

I've tried with `view.bringToFront();`, `view.setZ();`, `view.setElevation();` but none of them works.

Now I guess this is about the layout hierarchy. How to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you're trying to do like `ShowcaseView`. You can find some in these links :

[FancyShowCaseView](https://github.com/faruktoptas/FancyShowCaseView) 
[MultiLamp](https://github.com/ujwalthote/MultiLamp)

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey trying to achieving  the same. Could you guide me a little how you have achieved it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the background color of touch item view and text color. when user click on it .

Comment: I think my question wasn't clear enough, I just updated it giving more information and images. So.. your suggestion is not really solving the problem. Actually, I think I could try it out by changing the background color of all the other items but the clicked one.
But it is kind of a huge workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this effect by sending the item view to the Window.DecorView.

You can just make a copy of the desired view you want to put in the front (in this case you want the layout used by the ViewHolder) and then

```
((ViewGroup)activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(yourView);
```

after that you can set Translations according to the original view. The new view will be in front of the dark overlay in the same place the previous view is

EDIT: I have a sample of what you can do:
The following code is C# (using Xamarin.Android), it should be easy to turn to Java.

```
        var productView = productsLayoutManager.FindViewByPosition(position);
        var cardView = productView.FindViewById<CardView>(Resource.Id.product_layout);

        int[] location = new int[2];
        productView.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
        int left = location[0];
        int top = location[1];

        selectedView = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ProductRow2, null);
        productsAdapter.CloneItemViewHolder(productView, ref selectedView);

        selectedView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(cardView.LayoutParameters);
        ((ViewGroup)activity.Window.DecorView).AddView(selectedView, cardView.Width, cardView.Height);

        selectedView.SetX(left);
        selectedView.SetY(top);
        selectedView.RequestLayout();
        activity.DimBackground();
```

The cardView is the main layout of the RecyclerView item Viewholder.

This is actual code in use, producing this:
[image: The image shows a recyclerView. One of the items have been selected and is showing a focus effect]